# C++ std::unique_ptr with custom deleter const conversion

Tags: c++11, constants, unique-ptr

The following code is valid in C++11 and can be used to convert to a const version of the underlying pointer type.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(10));
std::unique_ptr<const int> b = std::move(a);
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing when using a unique_ptr with a custom deleter?

```
std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> a = std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>(new int(10), [](int*){});
std::unique_ptr<const int, ???> b = std::move(a);
```

As I would expect (due to the different types) I get compiler errors whether I use int* or const int* for the deleter argument in the const definition.

Some context: I'm trying to typedef a drop-in replacement unique_ptr signature that works with a custom allocator and can be used wherever unique_ptr was used e.g.

```
template <typename T> using CustomUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(???)>>;
```

Comment: Well, you have a deleter that wants a non-const pointer. Naturally, you can't move it into a `unique_ptr` that only has a const pointer, and needs a deleter capable of deleting it. If you use a suitable deleter from the start, then [it would work](http://rextester.com/EWXKSE80845).

Comment: Yeah good idea. Is that how the default deleter of unique_ptr works by forcing the argument of the deleter to always be const?

Comment: No, [`std::default_delete<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) has `operator()` taking `T*`. However, it also provides a converting constructor taking an arbitrary `std::default_delete<U>` (the constructor does nothing, as the deleter is stateless). That's how you can construct `std::unique_ptr<const T, std::default_delete<const T>>`  from `std::unique_ptr<T, std::default_delete<T>>`. `std::function`, on the other hand, cannot morph its signature like that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Not quite arbitrary - it restricts convertibility the other way around. `std::default_delete<T>` is convertible to `std::default_delete<U>` if `T*` is convertible to `U*`; `std::function<void(T*)>` is convertible to `std::function<void(U*)>` if `U*` is convertible to `T*`.